# openconnect displayed conncect succesful, but actually cannot access source on vpn network

Tags: openvpn

I had install the openconnect plugin, and configure it well, when connect vpn, it displayed successful, but actually, I cannot get the vpn network IP address, and ping the vpn network IP failed. what is this issue and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Did you upgrade to Ubuntu 12.10 recently? I did that and my openconnect VPN stopped working after that.
Turns out, I had never bothered to configure the firewall to allow VPN connections in the first place. I had kept it off for so long, I had forgotten that it was turned **off**.
After the upgrade, it was turned **on** by default, blocking my VPN connections.
After turning it off again (command line **ufw** or using **Firestarter** GUI), my VPN started working normally again...
Hope that helps.